# Копирование элементов одного списка в другой JAVA

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть 2 списка:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(...);
...
List<E> copy = new ArrayList<>();
```

Необходимо скопировать содерижимое list в copy так, чтобы при изменении элементов copy не менялись элементы list. Т.е. в copy должны лежать копии элементов, которые лежат в list.
Подходы вроде Collections.addAll() лишь копируют список.

Пока есть только одна идея - добавить в класс конструктор, который принимает объект и инициализирует значениями его полей свои. Такой подход не удобен в связи с иерархией типа E(внутри лежат также его наследники). Да и в случае, если полей много - такое себе решение.

Может есть еще варианты?

Comment: `public virtual E E.Clone() { ... }`

Comment: вопрос по Java, virtual явно не отсюда. Через клонирование возможно и можно зайти, но опять же нужно определить такой метод в каждом подклассе, которые расширяет суперкласс. Неужели нет чего-то простого, на поверхности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать через метод `java.lang.Object::clone()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> array = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<MyObject> copiedArray = array.stream().map(MyObject::clone).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static class MyObject implements Cloneable {
    private final int value;

    public MyObject(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject clone() {
        try {
            return (MyObject) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Но я бы порекомендовал все же, явно реализовать копирование полей у объектов

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы изменения в одном списке не отражались на элементах другого, эти элементы должны быть разными. То есть, нужно создать новые копии каждого объекта исходного списка.

Конкретная реализация копирования объектов E может быть разной. Как уже написали, это может быть переопределение метода clone. Либо написание своего метода E::deepClone(), который будет переопределяться в наследниках. Либо, как вы указали конструктор E(E e). Либо отдельный утилитарный метод.

В любом случае, операцию копирования стоит определить вручную и простого пути здесь нет.

Копирование списка можно выполнить через stream.

Метод класса E
List copy = list.stream().map(E::deepClone).collect(Collectors.toList());
Конструктор
List copy = list.stream().map(E::this).collect(Collectors.toList());
Утилитарный метод
List copy = list.stream().map(EUtils::deepClone).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: И вам большое спасибо за объяснение

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вариант с сериализацией/десериализацией:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static E.seriale;

class E implements Serializable {
    int i;
    E(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }
    public static E seriale(E el){
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("serial.tmp");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        ){
            oos.writeObject(el);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("serial.tmp");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ){
            return (E)ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class App0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new E(1));
        list.add(new E(2));
        list.add(new E(3));

        List<E> copy = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            copy.add(seriale(list.get(i)));
        }
    }

}
```